# Getting hostname from session ID

Tags: selenium, hostname

C# code 
we are having our code running in 3 nodes. We have a special requirement where we will need to know the hostname in run time where the script is running. I already got the session id

```
     string sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver)this.Driver).SessionId.ToString();
```

already tried below method. But in reader there is no parameter for hostname

```
       string url = "http://localhost:8080/grid/api/testsession?session=" + sessionId;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

I want to get hostname from session id which i have already received

Comment: What do you mean by _hostname_? Can you give us an example?

Comment: AFIK you can not get hostname of node . If you want ip address of node then you can get it using proxyId from the response of URL you are hitting.